# Unable to access rails server from local network in OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, nginx, configuration, firewall

I have a local rails app that runs on 
http://192.168.1.6:3002

I started the rails server using

passenger start -b 192.168.1.6 -p 3002 or passenger start -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3002

```
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /Users/oscar/Documents/Work/PW/backend/backend/tmp/pids/passenger.3002.pid
Log file: /Users/oscar/Documents/Work/PW/backend/backend/log/passenger.3002.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3002/
```

I'm able to access the app through the browser locally. However , when I try to access the web app from another system in the sam local network , its unable to connect.

I am running OSX 10.11.4 and I did whatever was required to open the port 3002 on mac. I have already added to my /etc/pf.conf. Rebooted my mac after that as I read in many places.

```
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 3200
```

Also at terminal I see the passenger running ngnix and listening for connections at the 0.0.0.0 bindnig.

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P

nginx-1.1 37803 oscar    5u  IPv4 0x7c83f81959513673      0t0  TCP *:3002 (LISTEN)
nginx-1.1 37804 oscar    5u  IPv4 0x7c83f81959513673      0t0  TCP *:3002 (LISTEN)
```

When I do a nmap, It does not show 3002 port listening.

```
nmap 192.168.1.6

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-17 06:20 IST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.6
Host is up (0.00040s latency).
Not shown: 971 closed ports, 27 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Can someone point out what step I am still missing thats preventing the rails app from being accessed through the local network.

Comment: have you disable os x firewall?

Comment: yes. I have disabled the firewall.